# search and highlight datas in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner in VBA, I've been searching in the internet that could possibly help me get any ideas about my problem.But I can't find any result that is closely related to what I've been searching for, so I came here. I can't wrote any macro about this because I don't even know where to start.I have an excel as my database containing an ID number and a last name of a person. I want to create a macro that has an input box.If the value/text is found anywhere in the workbook the cell is highlighted in yellow. Any suggestions will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Accept answers to previous questions you've asked.
2. Use google. First search for "Excel VBA input box", then "Excel VBA find". That should get you started.

Answer (score 3):

If you can do without the input box and just enter your search text into a cell instead, I have a solution that involves no macros.

Just use conditional formatting instead. If the first cell of your data was say B2, highlight that cell and select conditional formatting from the ribbon menu, then New Rule followed by Use formula. In the format values enter the following:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FIND($D$1,B2,1)))
```

Where B2 is you highlighted data cell and $D$1 is the cell where you are entering your search text. You can change the search cell location but must have the $$s.

Next hit the format button and change the fill color to yellow, then click OK.

All you then need to do is copy the format from the first data cell to the rest of the column.